# I need a simple proxy app to modify user agent header.

Tags: internet, proxy

I use a GSM internet plan for accessing internet from my laptop. They allow only one application to use internet at a time. I think they track the application with their user agent. So installing a proxy on my laptop and modifies all user agent to a single one may solve my problem.

So please suggest me a good proxy software for the problem. I tried CNTLM, but it didnt modify the user agent, eventhough it has an option for that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using **[mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/)** (may need some Python scripting) or **[Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/)**.

In Privoxy, you can just set the [`hide-user-agent`](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#HIDE-USER-AGENT) setting.

I wonder if that will actually fix it.  What a horrible ISP.